# Viewing the function code downloaded from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently learning AWS Lambda. I uploaded a nodejs code as AWS Lambda function. Out of my curiosity I selected "Download Function Code" option in "Actions" in AWS Lambda console. The file downloaded is of format "File". I want to view the node js code I uploaded from the downloaded file. I tried online File to text converters. But in vain. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: linux based computer? just run 'cat <file>' to see contents. if Windows , use Notepad. it's probably text based.

Answer (score 1):

`file <your file>` on linux/unix to find the data type.

Should be zip in the case of AWS lambda. You can just add `.zip` extension to the binary file you downloaded.